# How add timestamp between two specific timestamp of an industrial equipment - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I'm working on the availability of a specific equipment. After several data processing I finally have the time in hours of the unavailability of the equipment.

By analyzing my results, I find that I have an unavailability of 41 hours in a day ... impossible.

I finally found the problem, here are two examples:

```
Date              Unavailability
2019-10-25                 41.47

Flag                       Timestamp
begin         2019-10-25 16:35:22.48
end           2019-10-27 09:50:31.71
begin         2019-10-29 14:04:33.09
end           2019-10-29 14:05:07.63
```

In example 1, I have a begin which starts on 10-25 but which ends on 27 ... while the company has closed at 5pm so they no longer produce. But the problem was not resolved before 27 at 9:50 a.m.

I found a solution but I still cruelly lack experience on the conditions of timestamps in pandas.

The business opens at 7:00 a.m. each day and closes at 5:00 p.m

The line with the "end  2019-10-27" flag **does not have the same date as the line before** the "begin 2019-10-25". To have the sequence begin-end with the same date,  so we must add:

```
Flag                   Timestamp
end       2019-10-25 17:00:00.00
begin     2019-10-27 07:00:00.00
```

We must add day(s) **ONLY** If the sequence begin-end are of different date. So we make the difference of the days, 27-25 = 2 and to complete the unavailability it takes the date between the begin and the end.

**no insertion** between end-begin sequences even if there are several days. between

```
Flag                   Timestamp
begin     2019-10-26 07:00:00.00
end       2019-10-26 17:00:00.00
```

If we go back to example 1 with concatenate, this gives:

```
Date              Unavailability
2019-10-25                 25min
2019-10-26                   10h 
2019-10-27               2h50min 

Flag                     Timestamp
begin       2019-10-25 16:35:22.48
end         2019-10-25 17:00:00.00
begin       2019-10-26 07:00:00.00
end         2019-10-26 17:00:00.00
begin       2019-10-27 07:00:00.00
end         2019-10-27 09:50:31.71
begin       2019-10-29 14:04:33.09
end         2019-10-29 14:05:07.63
```

With an other example :

```
Date              Unavailability
2019-10-21                   10h

Flag                   Timestamp
begin     2019-10-21 15:30:22.48
end       2019-10-22 08:30:31.71
```

Same reflection, the alarm starts on 2019-10-21 and ends on 2019-10-22 so the unavailability of 10am is not good. Because you have to take into account the business hours. we make the difference of the dates: 22-21 = 1 so we must add:

```
Flag                   Timestamp
end          2019-10-21 17:00:00
begin        2019-10-22 07:00:00
```

with concatenate, this gives:

```
Date              Unavailability
2019-10-21                  1h30
2019-10-21                  1h30

Flag                   Timestamp
begin     2019-10-21 15:30:22.48
end       2019-10-21 17:00:00.00
begin     2019-10-22 07:00:00.00
end       2019-10-22 08:30:31.71
```

A sample of my dataframe:

```
Flag                     Timestamp
begin   2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889
end     2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102
begin   2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073
end     2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782
begin   2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574
end     2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
begin   2019-10-29 14:04:33.095633
end     2019-10-29 14:05:07.639344
begin   2019-10-29 14:13:07.924966
end     2019-10-29 14:13:08.888890
```

Thank you for your time !

The proof :

```
start   Tranc   dayofMonth  lapse   TrancRecalibration
0   2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889  begin   25.0    0.0     1
1   2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102  end     25.0    0.0     2
2   2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073  begin   25.0    0.0     1
3   2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782  end     25.0    0.0     2
4   2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574  begin   25.0    0.0     1
5   2019-10-25 17:00:22.485574  end     NaN     0.0     2
7   2019-10-26 07:00:39.914889  begin   NaN     1.0     1
6   2019-10-26 17:00:39.914889  end     NaN     1.0     2
11  2019-10-27 07:00:39.914889  begin   NaN     1.0     1
8   2019-10-27 08:00:31.713192  begin   NaN     0.0     1
9   2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192  end     27.0    0.0     2
10  2019-10-27 17:00:39.914889  end     NaN     1.0     2
15  2019-10-28 07:00:39.914889  begin   NaN     1.0     1
12  2019-10-28 14:04:33.095633  begin   28.0    0.0     1
14  2019-10-28 14:05:07.639344  end     28.0    0.0     2
13  2019-10-28 14:13:07.924966  begin   28.0    0.0     1
16  2019-10-28 14:13:08.888890  end     28.0    0.0     2
17  2019-10-28 17:00:39.914889  end     NaN     1.0
```

Really it's great what you did, I never succeeded ...

Just one last point if you allow it:

this is the result with the change from 4:55 pm to 7:00 am.

As we can notice we have:

begin 7:00 am
begin 8:00 am
end   9:50 a.m.
end   5:00 p.m.
begin 7:00 am
begin 2:04 p.m.
.
.
end 2:13 p.m.
end 5:00 p.m.

For calculation in relation to my alarms. I have to have an alternate begin end each time.
so if I have two begin that follow I would like to remove 7:00 am and if I have two end that follow I would like to delete 5:00 pm please.

Comment: can you show a sample of your DataFrame?

Comment: @Mark I updated the question with a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have wished to make it brief but have to ensure you understand how I went about it. Lets know if we got you wrong.

Dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Tranc':['begin', 'end', 'begin', 'end', 'begin', 'end', 'begin', 'end', 'begin', 'end'], 'lapse':[-1.0, -1.0, -42.0, -15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0],'start':['2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889', '2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102', '2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073', '2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782', '2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574', '2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192', '2019-10-28 14:04:33.095633', '2019-10-28 14:05:07.639344', ' 2019-10-28 14:13:07.924966', '2019-10-28 14:13:08.888890']})
```

Coerce date to datetime and set date start as index

```
df['start']=pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df.set_index('start', inplace=True)
```

Calculate time difference to identify 1 day differences

```
df['dayofMonth']=df.index.day
df['lapse']=df.dayofMonth.diff().fillna(0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

[Insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) rows where there is a day difference

```
k = df.index[df.lapse >=1]
insertdata= pd.DataFrame({'lapse':[-1]})
df2= pd.DataFrame(insertdata.values.tolist() * len(k), 
                   columns=insertdata.columns, index=k-1)
res = pd.concat([df, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Forward [backfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.bfill.html#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.bfill) insertion so that we resolve issues with existing dates and prepare the `df` for filling missing dates

```
res.Tranc=res.Tranc.bfill()
res.start=res.start.ffill()
res.sort_values(by='Tranc', ascending=True)
res
```

Query days inserted and mask

```
m=(res['lapse']==-1.0) & (res['Tranc']=='end')
mask=(res['lapse']==-1.0) & (res['Tranc']=='begin')
```

Edit inserted end beginning hours

```
res.loc[m, 'start']= res.loc[m, 'start'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(hour=17, minute=0))
res.loc[mask, 'start']= res.loc[mask, 'start'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(hour=8, minute=0))
res.drop(columns=['lapse'], inplace=True)

res.sort_values(by='start')
```

**Part Two** Insert missing dates and attribute them as required. Please note I have chosen to make starting time `7:00` and ending time `17:00` to make it easier to sort and also with the knowledged we are only filling in dates. You can change if required.

Convert res and rest it for next phase.

```
res2=res
res2
res2.set_index(res2['start'], inplace=True)
res2.drop(columns=['start'],inplace=True)
#df['dates']=df.index.date
res2.reset_index(inplace=True)
res2.set_index('start', inplace=True)
res2['lapse']=0
res2
```

Insert missing dates while keeping duplicates

```
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=pd.date_range(res2.index.min(), res2.index.max(), freq='D'))
df2=pd.concat([res2,s[~s.index.isin(res2.index)]]).sort_index()
df2.lapse.fillna(1, inplace=True)#Fill lapse with 1, so that can use that in df.repeat to replicate rows
df2.drop(columns=0, inplace=True)#default column, get rid of it
df2
```

For the inserted rows, replicate them. I use the integer in lapse to dictate how many times each index can be replicated and save the replicas in new df3.

```
df3=df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2.lapse)]
df3
```

Concat `df2` and `df3` in a new temp df `res3`

```
res3 = pd.concat([df2, df3]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=False)
res3.rename(columns={'index':'start'}, inplace=True)
res3
```

Introduce new  column in which I insert pattern 1 2, 1;begin and 2;end fro later use

```
res3['TrancRecalibration']=0
np.put(res3['TrancRecalibration'], np.arange(len(res3)), [1,2])
res3
```

Select all rows with Tranc, meaning they have already been set in phase 1 into `df4` and reset index so that we can use it to concat later

```
df4=res3[res3['Tranc'].notna()]
df4.set_index('start', inplace=True)
df4['Date']=df4.index.date
df4.reset_index(inplace=True)
df4.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df4
```

Select the recently inserted missing dates

```
df5=res3[res3['Tranc'].isna()]

df5['TrancRecalibration']=0
np.put(df5['TrancRecalibration'], np.arange(len(df5)), [1,2])
df5
```

mask df5 to isolate by `TrancRecalibration` (1 or 2) signifying beginning or end and attribute the `Tranc`

```
n=df5['TrancRecalibration']==1
l=df5['TrancRecalibration']==2
df5['Tranc']=np.where(n,'begin','end')
```

Set start and end time  to 7:00 and 17:00 respectively

```
df5.loc[n, 'start']= df5.loc[n, 'start'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(hour=7, minute=00))
df5.loc[l, 'start']= df5.loc[l, 'start'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(hour=17, minute=0))
```

reset index for `df5` so that can be concat to `df4`

```
df5.set_index('start', inplace=True)
df5['Date']=df5.index.date
df5.reset_index(inplace=True)
df5.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df5
```

Concat `df4` and `df5` into result

```
result = pd.concat([df4, df5]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by='start')
result
```

Output

[image]

Following your request to restrict starting time to 7am in case of a row insertion. You can use the following to drop consecutive `begin begin` and `end end` in a row

Define Patterns

```
pattern1=['begin', 'begin']
```

Drop the first appearances in the pattern sequence `['begin', 'begin']`

```
p1=(result.Tranc==pattern1[0])&(result["Tranc"].shift(-1)==pattern1[1])
# p1 indicates the first begin in a pettern of begin begin
result2=result[~p1]# drops the first begin in a pattern of begin begin
```

Repeat the above step but this time dropping the last entry in sequence pattern `['end', 'end']`

```
pattern2=['end', 'end']
p2=(result2.Tranc==pattern2[1])&(result2["Tranc"].shift(1)==pattern2[0])

result2[~p2].sort_values(by='start')
```

Final output

[image]

From here, proceed and analyse your unaivailability:

Comment: I tried with my real df (larger) but it doesn't work ... I add the proof in the subject

Comment: What warning do you get?

Comment: I don't have a warning, but it is not the expected result
I only need to have the insertion when the begin starts on a date "n" and end on the date n + 1. But in the example with you code, the program do an insertion that should not be.

Comment: happy to help but do not understand your requirement. My code inserts a blank row where.the day ifference is 1day so that a new datetime is inserted to flatten the 1 day. Did you want two rows inserted？Give example and we will find time to try

Comment: thank you for your time and for your help. I modified the starting statement with more explanation and examples. If you need more clarification don't hesitate

Comment: Great job !!!!!!!!! 
Just a last point, can you fixe my last note please...?

Comment: Lets see if that serves the purpose. My fear dropping ends up doing away with observed and may leave generated hence defiling the data

Comment: Thank you for your time, patience and great help !!! Yes sometime it can be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

nI would first transform the df to have separate begin and end columns:

```
df1['begin'] = df[df['Flag']=='begin']['Timestamp']
df1['end'] = df[df['Flag']=='end']['Timestamp']
```

then calculate the time to `end` and time to 17:00, take the min() of the two:

```
df1['time_to_end'] = df1['end'] - df1['begin']
df1['time_to_17'] = pd.Timestamp(year = df1['begin'].dt.year, month = df1['begin'].dt.month, day = df1['begin'].dt.day ,hour=17, minute=0) - df1['begin']
df1['Unavailibility'] = df1[['time_to_end','time_to_17']].min(1)
```

The you need to groupby date:

```
df1[['begin','Unavailibility']].set_index('begin').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).sum()
```

Comment: For my treatment I need to respect the format of the columns Flag and timestamp

Comment: The column 'Unavilibility' will have the number you are looking for to paste to your format df

Comment: your code with pd.Timestamp, doesn't work. 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: sorry, I was offline for a bit, you are right, it needs `.dt`

Comment: I add .dt but this time I have this error : cannot convert the series to <class 'in'>

Comment: May not be well fitting but try and see. I had a go after I learnt a new concept to apply to a project I am doing at work. Let see

Comment: Had ago again. Please lets know if we got you wrong. Tried to detail each step. Happy to  elaborate or improve